# Two element hit in canvas

Tags: wpf

I have a bomb(element) in the canvas that is moving with doublanimation(vertical only) and I want to see if it hits an airplane(also an element on the canvas).
I wrote this code:

```
private bool HitCheck()
{
    AirPlaneRect.Location = airplane.PointToScreen(new Point(Canvas.GetLeft(airplane), Canvas.GetTop(airplane)));

    Rect BombPos = new Rect(bombPoint.X, Canvas.GetTop(this),this.bombImage.Height, this.bombImage.Width);

    if (BombPos.IntersectsWith(AirPlaneRect))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

but for some reason the bomb location is always the starting one.
I'm using a timer that call this method every half a second.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `Timer` to check periodic if they intersects, it is more accurate to check it when the `DoubleAnimation` is changed. When that happens, `CurrentTimeInvalidated` is raised.

I created a little sample to demonstrate what I mean. Here is the XAML:

```
<Canvas>
    <!--be shure to assign Top and Left of all objects-->
    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Name="bomb"
               Width="20" Height="100" Fill="gray"/>
    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="200" Name="airPlane"
               Width="300" Height="50" Fill="lightblue"/>
    <Canvas.Triggers>
        <!--Run the animation at startup-->
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard >
                <Storyboard >
                    <DoubleAnimation Name="doubleAnimation"
                                     Storyboard.TargetName="bomb" 
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"
                                     From="0" To="400" Duration="0:0:5"
                                     CurrentTimeInvalidated="CurrentTimeInvalidated"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Canvas.Triggers>
</Canvas>
```

And the code behind:

```
private void CurrentTimeInvalidated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HitTest(airPlane, bomb))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hit!");
        //unregister the event handler to avoid to see the messagebox more than once
        doubleAnimation.CurrentTimeInvalidated -= CurrentTimeInvalidated;
    }
}

static bool HitTest(FrameworkElement airPlane, FrameworkElement bomb)
{
    var r1 = new Rect(Canvas.GetLeft(airPlane), Canvas.GetTop(airPlane), airPlane.ActualWidth, airPlane.ActualHeight);
    var r2 = new Rect(Canvas.GetLeft(bomb), Canvas.GetTop(bomb), bomb.ActualWidth, bomb.ActualHeight);

    return r1.IntersectsWith(r2);
}
```

If you do it similar to me, it should work. Or is your code structure significant different to my?

Comment: the code is pretty similar(im using c# only because im not that strong at XAML :-) ) but it still does not work.  i've registerd the event handler to the animation but it's never activated. also im not using storyboard. any ideas? (thanks for the help btw)

Comment: @Daniel When you does not use a storyboard, how did you solve the movement? I think it would be the best when you set a break point at the `IntersectsWith`  and look at the values. 
BTW, if you use WPF, you should learn a Little bit XAML. It is not very difficult but can help you in nearly all questions related to GUI.